# TF calculation of nested list with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, lambda, mapreduce

I have a nested list of words and I want to find the TF (term frequency) of each word, defined as: TF = num times term appears in document/num terms in the document. Each list is of a different size:

```
nested_list = [["dog", "fox", "ox"],
               ["cow", "dog", "cat", "snake"],
               ["fox", "dog"]]

rdd = sc.parallelize(nested_list)

word_occurencies = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(i, 1) for i in x])\
                    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

So now I have:

```
word_occurencies.take(3)
[("dog", 3),
("fox", 2),
("cat", 1)]
```

Now, TF of "dog" would be number of occurencies (3) divided by total terms in the document (2)

I tried:

```
tf = word_occurencies.map(lambda x: (x[1]/len(nested_list[i] for i in nested_list)))
```

Comment: Can you explain why for dogs `total terms in the document = 2`?